# How access to response http headers from 'didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge' delegate method

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, http-headers, nsurlconnection

I need to deal with an http authentication (401) using the NSURLConnection class, so I implemented the "connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:" delegate method.

In this method, to respond to the server challenge, I need an information contained in the http server response headers (the WWW-Authenticate header one). My problem is how can I access this headers from this method ?

(I saw that the response headers are available from the NSURLResponse object (allHeaderFields method), but this object is passed to "connection:didReceiveResponse:" delegate method, too late to respond to the server challenge. )

Regards.
Sébastien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSURLAuthenticationChallenge` has a `-failureResponse` method. If that object is an `NSHTTPURLResponse` (and it should be for HTTP connections!), you can query it for `-allHeaderFields`.

Comment: Right Mike, it works fine. 
Thanks a lot.
Regards.
Sébastien.